# minutes of two telephone servecies

Tags: python

```
def main():
account = intput("Enter an account number:")
service = input("enter service code")
number = input("enter number of minutes used")
while service > 50:
    service 50 * (.20)
    if service < 50:
        service 50 * (.10)



       if daymin > 75:
          daymin =  (-75 ** (.10))

        if nightmin > 100
           nightmin =  (-100 ** (.05))
main()
```

I keep getting an error where my service 50 * (.20) is. I keep rearanging my code to try to fit it in and there still an error. I am trying to fiqure out two telephone servecies of one company.

Comment: Try fixing your indentation, it seems inconsistent at the moment.

Comment: Whats `service 50 * (.20)` supposed to do?

Comment: It supposed to be for the regular services

Comment: Do you mean `service = 50 * (.20)`? I would recommend moving the rates to variables to avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: that 50 keeps giving me an error